# Apache HTTPD aliases and directories in a virtual host

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, vhosts

The configuration of my VirtualHost on Apache HTTPD 2.4 is driving me crazy.
I have a simple directory structure :

```
/my/root
|_ dir1
|_ dir2
```

I want my VirtualHost to serve `dir2` for each request at `http://my.domain/sub`. And `dir1` for any other request at `http://my.domain`.

The following configuration serves the `dir2` directory as expected.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.domain
    DocumentRoot "/my/root"
    
    Alias /sub/ /my/root/dir2
    
    <Directory "/my/root/dir2">
        ...
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But as soon as I do this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.domain
    DocumentRoot "/my/root"
    
    Alias /sub/ /my/root/dir2/
    Alias / /my/root/dir1
    
    <Directory "/my/root/dir1">
        ...
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/my/root/dir2">
        ...
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

or this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.domain
    DocumentRoot "/my/root/dir1"
    
    Alias /sub/ /my/root/dir2/
    
    <Directory "/my/root/dir1">
        ...
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/my/root/dir2">
        ...
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It all goes wrong. `dir1` is served, but `dir2` is not anymore...

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
    Alias /sub /my/root/dir2
    <Directory /my/root/dir2>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        FallbackResource /index.php
    </Directory> 

    DocumentRoot /my/root/dir1
    <Directory /my/root/dir1>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        FallbackResource /index.html
    </Directory>
```